# T-SQL ALL in case statment

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to join subcategories and ALL (all subcategories) in one column in SQL?

For example I have this table

[image]

I want to have:

[image]

In CASE like below I have count for categories but not for All.

```
CASE WHEN a THEN COUNT(a)
, CASE WHEN b THEN COUNT(b)
CASE WHEN c THEN COUNT(c)
```

Comment: Unclear why you need `CASE`. Your desired results could be got with `GROUP BY`/`ROLLUP`

Comment: As per the question guide, please DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: What is your end requirement? Showsing totals is usually a function of the display application.

Comment: I dont need CASE. I need sum for all categories. CASE was my first choise. I will try GROUP BY.

Comment: SQL solutions work, but if your goal is to produce a report then I would suggest SQL Server Reporting Services which includes Summing functionality for a dataset, and other various formatting.

Answer (score 2):

like this?

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(Category VARCHAR(32), [COUNT] INT)
INSERT INTO #temp(Category, [COUNT])
VALUES('a', 2), ('b', 3), ('b1', 4), ('a', 1), ('b', 1)

SELECT ISNULL(Category, 'All') AS Category
       , SUM([COUNT]) as [COUNT]
FROM #temp
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS(Category, ())
```

GROUP BY, GROUPING SETS, ROLLUP, CUBE and UNION ALL, these can achieve similar functions, and UNION ALL should be your last choice (performance issues), hope this can help you.

Comment: Note that if `Category` is nullable then you would need instead `CASE WHEN GROUPING(Category) = 0 THEN Category ELSE 'All' END`

Answer (score 0):

Following query might solve your issue:

```
SELECT Category, SUM(Count) AS Count
FROM [dbo].[YourTable] 
GROUP BY Category

UNION ALL

SELECT 'ALL', SUM(Count)
FROM [dbo].[YourTable]
```